# How to tell normal Python function from generator by looking at the AST?

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

I need to detect whether a `ast.FunctionDef` in Python 3 AST is normal function definition or a generator definition.

Do I need to traverse the body and look for `ast.Yield`-s or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a sneaky way to do this is you compile the AST instance with `compile`. The code object has a couple of flags attached to it, one of them being `'GENERATOR'`, that you can use to distinguish these. Of course this depends on certain compilation flags so it isn't really portable across CPython versions or implementations

For example, with a non-generator function:

```
func = """
def spam_func():
    print("spam")
"""
# Create the AST instance for it
m = ast.parse(func)
# get the function code
# co_consts[0] is used because `m` is 
# compiled as a module and we want the 
# function object
fc = compile(m, '', 'exec').co_consts[0]
# get a string of the flags and 
# check for membership
from dis import pretty_flags
'GENERATOR' in pretty_flags(fc.co_flags)  # False
```

Similarly, for a `spam_gen` generator, you'd get:

```
gen = """
def spam_gen():
    yield "spammy"
"""    
m = ast.parse(gen)
gc = compile(m, '', 'exec').co_consts[0]
'GENERATOR' in pretty_flags(gc.co_flags)  # True
```

This might be more sneaky than what you need though, traversing the AST is another viable option that's probably more understandable and portable.

---

If you have a function object instead of an AST you can always perform the same check by using `func.__code__.co_flags`:

```
def spam_gen():
    yield "spammy"

from dis import pretty_flags
print(pretty_flags(spam_gen.__code__.co_flags))
# 'OPTIMIZED, NEWLOCALS, GENERATOR, NOFREE'
```

Answer (score 3):

Traversing the AST would be harder than it seems -- using the compiler is probably the way to go. Here's an example of why looking for a Yield node isn't as simple as it sounds.

```
>>> s1 = 'def f():\n  yield'
>>> any(isinstance(node, ast.Yield) for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(s1)))
True
>>> dis.pretty_flags(compile(s1, '', 'exec').co_consts[0].co_flags)
'OPTIMIZED, NEWLOCALS, GENERATOR, NOFREE'
```

```
>>> s2 = 'def f():\n  def g():\n    yield'
>>> any(isinstance(node, ast.Yield) for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(s2)))
True
>>> dis.pretty_flags(compile(s2, '', 'exec').co_consts[0].co_flags)
'OPTIMIZED, NEWLOCALS, NOFREE'
```

The AST approach would probably require using NodeVisitor to exclude functions and lambda bodies.